# Python help() function and the string.title function

Tags: python

Why doesn't

```
import string;help(string.title)
```

seem to work but

```
help(string.strip)
```

works just fine?

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no
>   attribute 'title'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`title` is a method on objects of type `str`, not a function in the `string` module. That means you can do `"foo".title()` or `str.title("foo")` but not `string.title("foo")`.

Answer (score 1):

`help(str.title)` seems to work just fine.

Comment: There must be some sort of distinction between str and string that I will need to read about then, thanks.

Comment: str is inbuilt, `string` is a module

Comment: `str` is the type of string literals.